# Visual Studio Code, atajo de teclado para rodear con etiqueta texto seleccionado

Tags: vscode

En Visual Studio Code, ¿Es posible realizar una selección de código y luego presionar una combinación de teclas para rodear el texto seleccionado con una determinada etiqueta? (Por ejemplo con un `div`).
Por ejemplo, si tengo el siguiente código:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <a href="#">Acerca de</a>
    <a href="#">Trabajos</a>
    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
</nav>
```

Lo que deseo saber es si luego de seleccionar el código, en Visual Studio Code existe una combinación de teclas que posibilite rodear todo el código seleccionado con otra etiqueta, por ejemplo un `div, para que luego el código quede así:

```
<div>
    <nav class="menu">
        <a href="#">Acerca de</a>
        <a href="#">Trabajos</a>
        <a href="#">Contacto</a>
    </nav>
<div>
```

Gracias.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una técnica llamada ZenCoding o, más recientemente, Emmet.
Los pasos serían algo asi:

- Seleccionas lo que deseas rodear
- **CTRL+SHIFT+P** (En el caso de windows)
- Luego escribes Emmet para que vaya filtrando y seleccionas la opción: **Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation**
- Finalmente escribes la etiqueta con la que deseas rodear y presionas enter.

Acá dejo la fuente: [Rodear un fragmento HTML](https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/truco-rodear-un-fragmento-de-codigo-con-etiquetas-html-en-visual-studio-code)